# Kendo Grid - make a column always appear as dropdown boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo grid which is being created in JS. This code is not mine, but someone else's, and I really don't think we should be changing many of the fundamentals of it. However, there is one column in it which we would ideally like to display as a dropdown box all the time, or at least look like one. Code is below:

```
self.caGridOptions = {
        widget: self.caKendoGrid,
        data: undefined,
        dataSource: {
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "number" },
                        description: { type: "string", editable: false },
                        value: { type: "number", editable: false },
                        caTypeDescription: { type: "string", editable: false }
                    }
                }
            },
            autoSync: true
        },
        sortable: true,
        scrollable: false,
        editable: true,
        columns: [
                { field: "id", title: "Code", width: 90, template: "#=pager.activePage$().ctx.getca ? pager.activePage$().ctx.getca(id, 'code') : id #", editor: self.caDropDownEditor },
                { field: "description", title: "Description", width: 90, template: "#=pager.activePage$().ctx.getca ? pager.activePage$().ctx.getca(id, 'description') : id #" },
                { field: "value", title: "Value", width: 90, format: "{0:n2}", template: "#=pager.activePage$().ctx.getca ? pager.activePage$().ctx.getca(id, 'value') : id #" },
                { field: "caTypeDescription", title: "Type", width: 90, template: "#=pager.activePage$().ctx.getca ? pager.activePage$().ctx.getca(id, 'caTypeDescription') : id #" },
                { width: 90, filterable: false, template: kendo.template('<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="delete"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;Delete</a>') }
        ],
        dataBound: self.gridButtons,
        noRecords: true,
        messages: {
            noRecords: "There is no data available"
        }
    };
    //
    // functions
    self.getca = function (id, type) {
        if (id == null) return null;
        return self.caOptions().filter(function (item) { return item.id == id; })[0][type];
    };
```

The ID field (first column) goes into a dropdown box when it is edited, as you can see. However, what we would like is for this to appear as a dropdown box all the time. Not necessarily by always having the editor on (which I believe would be impossible, as Kendo can only turn the editor on on one row at a time), but perhaps by simply formatting it like a dropdown.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated. It's annoying as this is a tiny, minor thing and we've got examples of it working elsewhere, but they're grids which have been written primarily in cshtml (using Kendo MVC, I think) and I really don't want to rewrite the entire grid for something so trivial, as well as possibly any other functions that rely on its data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary issue you are facing is that the cell is just a table cell until you actually start editing.  At that time, it dynamically creates the input.

I had a similar requirement in the past and it ended up being easier to decorate the cell to look like a drop-down as opposed to trying to render a drop-down in every row of the grid.  This allows you to keep the default grid behavior intact and allows the user to see that there will be a list of values when they edit that cell.  We ended up just putting a down-arrow icon to the right of the value in the display template - from your code, it looks like you are using some font-awesome icons, but there are some delivered by Kendo UI as well - so, the template could be something like this:

```
template: '#=id# <span class="k-icon k-icon-s"></span>'
```

**UPDATE:**

The kendo icons do depend on your version and I had a typo in the name above.  In any case, here is an example you can look at:

This Kendo demo shows adding a custom editor (dropdown) on the Category column:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom

If you scroll down, there is a button to "Edit this Example" - here, you'll see that the Category column uses a template:

```
template: "#=Category.CategoryName#"
```

You can change the template to the following to create a drop-down looking effect:

```
template: "<span style='border-style:solid; border-width: 1px; padding: 4px; width: 150px; display: block'>#=Category.CategoryName# <span class='k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down' style='float:right'></span></span>"
```

You can tune the css to get it closer to exactly what you want, but this give you the idea.  Other possibilities include actually defining css classes that can be applied so you don't need to include so much in-line styling.

Comment: Unfortunately just a down arrow wouldn't suffice (and I don't think we're using the same icons as I just tried your code and it didn't work). I'm currently trying to re-write the grid now as the client's quite keen on this.

Comment: Thanks - eventually managed to get it working, using a lot of spans and messing around with padding/margins.